# Split numpy array into several arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, split

I have x and y like this:

```
x = np.array([[2,3,5,6], [1,2,4,3], [1,5,6,4], [2,8,9,5]])
y = np.array([1,0,1,2])
```

And I need do this. Separate array into several arrays according to y values. X and y numbers can be different and also number of values into brackets can be different.

```
x_0 = np.array([1,2,4,3])
x_1 = np.array([[2,3,5,6], [1,5,6,4]])
x_2 = np.array([2,8,9,5])
```

I tried to do it with dictionaries and lists but probably someone can do it shorter

Comment: "Separate array into several arrays according to y values.": the logic is unclear to me: why is x_1 2 by 4, instead of having 4 new arrays of length 4, since there are 4 numbers in y. What is the logic that the 0th and 2nd subarray in x need to be grouped together?

Answer (score 4):

You ca, achieve this in pure [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) (without loops) with [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and [`array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html), then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the output to form a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
n, cnt = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

out = dict(zip(n, np.array_split(x[np.argsort(y)], np.cumsum(cnt[:-1]))))
```

Output:

```
{0: array([[1, 2, 4, 3]]),
 1: array([[2, 3, 5, 6],
           [1, 5, 6, 4]]),
 2: array([[2, 8, 9, 5]])}
```

How it works:

```
# get the unique `y` values and their count
n, cnt = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
# array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 1])

# reorder the array
x[np.argsort(y)]
# array([[1, 2, 4, 3],    # 0
#        [2, 3, 5, 6],    # 1
#        [1, 5, 6, 4],    # 1
#        [2, 8, 9, 5]])   # 2

# get the split points
np.cumsum(cnt[:-1])
# array([1, 3])

# split
np.array_split(x[np.argsort(y)], np.cumsum(cnt[:-1]))
# [array([[1, 2, 4, 3]]),
#  array([[2, 3, 5, 6],
#         [1, 5, 6, 4]]),
#  array([[2, 8, 9, 5]])]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do what you need:

```
result = [[] for _ in range(max(y) + 1)]
for idx, arr in zip(y, x):
    result[idx].append(arr)
```

If you know that there are exactly three lists in result then:

```
x_0, x_1, x_2 = map(np.array, result)
```

Result:

```
>>> x_0
array([[1, 2, 4, 3]])
>>> x_1
array([[2, 3, 5, 6],
       [1, 5, 6, 4]])
>>> x_2
array([[2, 8, 9, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick list comprehension:

```
[x[y==i] for i in range(y.max() + 1)] 

Out[]: 
[array([[1, 2, 4, 3]]),
 array([[2, 3, 5, 6],
        [1, 5, 6, 4]]),
 array([[2, 8, 9, 5]])]
```

Unfortunately this method generates arrays of non-constant shape, so listing is probably your best bet.